# After adding Scroll View Image Silder is does not show

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library

I am trying to show a image silder but the after adding scroll view my image silder is does not show.

My activity.xml:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_outer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout_outer">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
            android:id="@+id/slider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            custom:pager_animation="Accordion"
            custom:auto_cycle="true"
            custom:indicator_visibility="visible"
            custom:pager_animation_span="1100" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_special_product_horizontal_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_special_produce_image01"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/shop240x320"
                        android:paddingRight="65dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/special_producr"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_special_produce_image02"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/shop240x320"
                        android:paddingRight="65dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/special_producr"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_special_produce_image03"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/shop240x320"
                        android:paddingRight="65dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/special_producr"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_special_produce_image04"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/shop240x320"
                        android:paddingRight="65dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/special_producr"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_special_produce_image05"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/shop240x320"
                        android:paddingRight="65dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/special_producr"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lineaar_layout_special_product_name01"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/lineaar_layout_special_product_name"
                        android:textColor="#00FF00"
                        android:layout_marginRight="85dp"/>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lineaar_layout_special_product_name02"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/lineaar_layout_special_product_name"
                        android:textColor="#00FF00"
                        android:layout_marginRight="85dp"/>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lineaar_layout_special_product_name03"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/lineaar_layout_special_product_name"
                        android:textColor="#00FF00"
                        android:paddingRight="85dp"/>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lineaar_layout_special_product_name04"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/lineaar_layout_special_product_name"
                        android:textColor="#00FF00"
                        android:paddingRight="85dp"/>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lineaar_layout_special_product_name05"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/lineaar_layout_special_product_name"
                        android:textColor="#00FF00"
                        android:paddingRight="85dp"/>




                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_special_product_price01"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/linear_layout_special_product_price"
                        android:textColor="#00FF00"
                        android:paddingRight="90dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_special_product_price02"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/linear_layout_special_product_price"
                        android:textColor="#00FF00"
                        android:paddingRight="90dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_special_product_price03"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/linear_layout_special_product_price"
                        android:textColor="#00FF00"
                        android:paddingRight="90dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_special_product_price04"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/linear_layout_special_product_price"
                        android:textColor="#00FF00"
                        android:paddingRight="90dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_special_product_price05"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/linear_layout_special_product_price"
                        android:textColor="#00FF00"
                        android:paddingRight="90dp"/>


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_special_product_mainprice01"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/linear_layout_special_product_mainprice"
                        android:textColor="#00FF00"
                        android:paddingRight="55dp"/>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_special_product_mainprice02"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/linear_layout_special_product_mainprice"
                        android:textColor="#00FF00"
                        android:paddingRight="55dp"/>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_special_product_mainprice03"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/linear_layout_special_product_mainprice"
                        android:textColor="#00FF00"
                        android:paddingRight="55dp"/>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_special_product_mainprice04"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/linear_layout_special_product_mainprice"
                        android:textColor="#00FF00"
                        android:paddingRight="55dp"/>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_special_product_mainprice05"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/linear_layout_special_product_mainprice"
                        android:textColor="#00FF00"
                        android:paddingRight="55dp"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/linear_layout_discount_horizontal_scroll_view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_discout_product_image01"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/shop240x320"
                            android:paddingRight="65dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/special_producr"/>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_discout_product_image02"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/shop240x320"
                            android:paddingRight="65dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/special_producr"/>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_discout_product_image03"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/shop240x320"
                            android:paddingRight="65dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/special_producr"/>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_discout_product_image04"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/shop240x320"
                            android:paddingRight="65dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/special_producr"/>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_discout_product_image05"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/shop240x320"
                            android:paddingRight="65dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/special_producr"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lineaar_layout_discout_product_name01"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/lineaar_layout_special_product_name"
                            android:textColor="#00FF00"
                            android:layout_marginRight="85dp"/>


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lineaar_layout_discout_product_name02"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/lineaar_layout_special_product_name"
                            android:textColor="#00FF00"
                            android:layout_marginRight="85dp"/>


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lineaar_layout_discout_product_name03"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/lineaar_layout_special_product_name"
                            android:textColor="#00FF00"
                            android:paddingRight="85dp"/>


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lineaar_layout_discout_product_name04"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/lineaar_layout_special_product_name"
                            android:textColor="#00FF00"
                            android:paddingRight="85dp"/>


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lineaar_layout_discout_product_name05"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/lineaar_layout_special_product_name"
                            android:textColor="#00FF00"
                            android:paddingRight="85dp"/>


                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_discout_product_price01"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/lineaar_layout_special_product_name"
                            android:textColor="#00FF00"
                            android:layout_marginRight="85dp"/>


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_discout_product_price02"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/lineaar_layout_special_product_name"
                            android:textColor="#00FF00"
                            android:layout_marginRight="85dp"/>


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_discout_product_price03"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/lineaar_layout_special_product_name"
                            android:textColor="#00FF00"
                            android:paddingRight="85dp"/>


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_discout_product_price04"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/lineaar_layout_special_product_name"
                            android:textColor="#00FF00"
                            android:paddingRight="85dp"/>


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_discout_product_price05"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/lineaar_layout_special_product_name"
                            android:textColor="#00FF00"
                            android:paddingRight="85dp"/>


                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_discout_product_mainprice01"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/lineaar_layout_special_product_name"
                            android:textColor="#00FF00"
                            android:layout_marginRight="85dp"/>


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_discout_product_mainprice02"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/lineaar_layout_special_product_name"
                            android:textColor="#00FF00"
                            android:layout_marginRight="85dp"/>


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_discout_product_mainprice03"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/lineaar_layout_special_product_name"
                            android:textColor="#00FF00"
                            android:paddingRight="85dp"/>


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_discout_product_mainprice04"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/lineaar_layout_special_product_name"
                            android:textColor="#00FF00"
                            android:paddingRight="85dp"/>


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_discout_product_mainprice05"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/lineaar_layout_special_product_name"
                            android:textColor="#00FF00"
                            android:paddingRight="85dp"/>


                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

            </HorizontalScrollView>


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I am trying to create layout like below image:-

[image]

In My Layout in top showing Toolbaar and below image slider and below other sections. cureently my layout show blow:-

[image]

After adding this `android:fillViewport="true"` line my layout show below:-[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your scrollview in xml

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: after adding this line my image slider is show but other section does not show

Comment: Try using a listview instead of scrollview.It will help

Comment: How to use ListView can u explain